# React-native-fs moveFile: ENOENT: no such file or directory, even though file exists

Tags: android, react-native

Using react native (0.44), react-native-fs (2.3.2) and react-native-zip. Trying to create a zip and then move it to another folder.

Expected:

- Create zip file of files at source folder to target path
- When success (promise resolves), move zip to another location

Actual:

- Zip file creation succeeds:

`Successfully created zip at /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_app/files/2017-06-07-14_09_39.zip`

- After zip creation promise resolves, check if source path exists:

`fs.exists('/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_app/files/2017-06-07-14_09_39.zip')`

-> `true`

But:

`fs.moveFile('/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_app/files/2017-06-07-14_09_39.zip', targetPath)`

-> `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_app/files/2017-06-07-14_09_39.zip'`

Read and write permissions are OK in AndroidManifest etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, totally have no idea why

Comment: did any of you ever figure out the solution?

Comment: Never figured it out - I just used react-native-fetch-blob for this because it had the same functionality and it worked. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Check that "targetPath" includes both target directory path and target filename. Also check that the target directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be you forgot to add the filename so the destPath also, it's not enough to specify a directory.